# C - 2D char pointer array realloc

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void init_pointer_arr(void)
{
char *arr[1];
int command_count = 1;
int length_counter = 1;
int fixed_cols = 5;

int i, j;

// malloc -first- initialization of the array
*arr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
if (arr == NULL) {
    printf("17:malloc NULL");
}

/**************************************DEBUG***************************/ 
// init with char 'a' for debug purpose
for (i = 0; i < command_count; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < length_counter*fixed_cols; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = 'a';
    }
}

// print
for (i = 0; i < command_count; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < length_counter*fixed_cols; j++)
    {
        printf("%c", arr[i][j]);
    }
}
\*************************************END DEBUG*******************/

printf("\nrealloc\n"); // DEBUG
// realloc
//arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(arr[0]));
arr[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
arr[1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
if (arr == NULL) 
{
    printf("51:malloc NULL");
}

/***************Re init newly allocate space for DEBUG*********************/
// init newly allocated space
for (i = 0; i < command_count; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < length_counter*fixed_cols; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = 's';
    }
}
printf("s\n"); // DEBUG
// print
for (i = 0; i < command_count; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < length_counter*fixed_cols; j++)
    {
        printf("%c", arr[i][j]);
    }
}

\******************************END DEBUG*****************************/

}

int main() {
init_pointer_arr();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I basically want to implement a 2d array with a pointer array, but I keep getting the error: "memory arround arr is corrupted" and the source of this error are these two lines:

```
    arr[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    arr[1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
```

I have seen other posts about this but no one seems to tackle thisproblem the way I am trying to, plus the code above compiles just fine with no warnings.

I am at loss, as to why this happens. any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT~ In the beginning arr has only one row, but at some point (troublesome code above) I want to add more rows, I have also tried realloc (you can see it in a comment in the same place as the other 2 above). But no luck there either.

Comment: `arr` is declared as `char *arr[1];`. this can only store one char *

Comment: @amdixon Yes, as I clarified in the EDIT, in the beginning I need only one row, but thenI am trying to add more. And that's when chaos ensues.

Comment: then you should store the char * s on the heap and realloc them. `char *arr[1]` is declaring stack storage for one

Comment: @amdixon Care to put that in code, please? I am very confused about dynamic allocation. As I have gathered from other posts, I need to realloc the values that already exist and then malloc the extra rows, but I can;t seem to get it to work properly.

Comment: `char **arr; arr = malloc(1*sizeof(char *)); // check for malloc error here; // your code..; temp = realloc(arr, 2*sizeof(char *)); // check for realloc error and assign temp to arr.. then can access arr[1] here`

Comment: @amdixon that seems to take care of my error, but now I have a problem when assigning a value and when printing the contents of it. If you care to make a complete answer I will pick  it as the answer to my Q.

Comment: **Which book are you reading? The reason I ask is that it's obvious whatever you're using now isn't working for you, because there are *many errors* in this code. I'm trying to hint towards the success that a certain book has achieved in the fifteen years it has been around in order to be so highly recommended by everyone... Hintedy hint. People who read the book don't commonly ask questions like this. Don't forget to do the exercises.**

Comment: I just want to clarify that the accepted answer doesn't even mention half of the issues here, just to give you some idea of the sheer number of errors that led me to conclude you aren't reading the book I'm referring to. You can find the book by looking into the history of C. Make sure you get the second edition.

Comment: does every row have the same number of columns?

Comment: @Seb why don't you just name the book you refer to instead of dancing around it?  Last thing OP needs is some guessing game about a book he might never have heard of.

Comment: @Seb No books right now, I'm just brushing up on my knowledge of C. What do you mean the code has errors? it compiles and runs without a problem now afaik & tested.

Comment: @M.M no. I need it to use as little memory as possible, it stores input, that reads one char at a time at the first row. It allocates a new row (ith an initial space)and then starts storing values to that row, once a specific char is inputed. If the total lengthof a row is exceeded it reallocates more space to it. So different rows may have different sizes.
The for loops above are merely for debuging purposes

Comment: @Mechanic If we were to say that undefined behaviour results in crashes, then we would be defining the undefined, wouldn't we? Part of the problem with undefined behaviour is that it *might work*, some of the time, but only by coincidence. It's not required to work as you would expect every time, or on every platform. **You need proper guidance to learn that which is defined behaviour**, as opposed to *undefined behaviour*. Proper guidance can come in the form of a book... and K&R, 2nd edition has decades of success guiding thousands and thousands of students. Don't forget to do the exercises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**issues**

> - storing char * array on the stack not allowing expansion
> - printing hardcoded line numbers ( which might change )
> - not exiting on failure ( eg malloc failure )
> - memory leaks ( not freeing the memory afterwards )
> - system("pause") is windows specific

**adjusted code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void init_pointer_arr(void)
{
/*  char *arr[1]; */
// store the char * s on the heap
  char **arr, **temp;
  int command_count = 1;
  int length_counter = 1;
  int fixed_cols = 5;

  int i, j;

// malloc storage for the char * s
  arr = malloc(command_count * sizeof(char *));
  if(!arr)
  {
    goto err0;
  }

//  malloc -first-
    arr[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
  if (arr[0] == NULL) {
//    printf("17:malloc NULL");
    printf("%d:malloc NULL\n", __LINE__);
    // should return on failure :
    goto err1;
  }

//  init
//  you might want to put some \n in these printfs..
    for (i = 0; i < command_count; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < length_counter*fixed_cols; j++)
      {
        arr[i][j] = 'a';
      }
    }

//  print
    for (i = 0; i < command_count; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < length_counter*fixed_cols; j++)
      {
        printf("%c", arr[i][j]);
      }
    }


  printf("\nrealloc\n");
//    realloc
  command_count = 2;
  temp = realloc(arr, command_count * sizeof(char *));
  if(!temp)
  {
    goto err2;
  }
  arr = temp;
//  arr[0] has already been alloced, not necessary again
//  and will cause a leak
//  arr[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
  arr[1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
  if (arr[1] == NULL) 
  {
    printf("%d:malloc NULL\n", __LINE__);
    goto err2;
  }


//  init newly allocated space
    for (i = 0; i < command_count; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < length_counter*fixed_cols; j++)
      {
        arr[i][j] = 's';
      }
    }
  printf("s\n");
//    print
    for (i = 0; i < command_count; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < length_counter*fixed_cols; j++)
      {
        printf("%c", arr[i][j]);
      }
    }

err3:
  free(arr[1]);
err2:
  free(arr[0]);
err1:
  free(arr);
err0:
  return ;
}

int main() {
  init_pointer_arr();
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32)
  system("pause");
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
$ gcc -g test.c -o test
$ valgrind ./test
==3612== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3612== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3612== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3612== Command: ./test
==3612== 
aaaaa
realloc
s
ssssssssss==3612== 
==3612== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3612==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3612==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 34 bytes allocated
==3612== 
==3612== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3612== 
==3612== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3612== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

---

**reference**

- [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/)
- [valgrind quickstart](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/QuickStart.html)
- [goto error handling - RAII](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/04/27/using-goto-for-error-handling-in-c/)

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot plusvery useful links. btw you have a typo 

 `arr[1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
  if (arr[1] == NULL) 
  {
    printf("51:malloc NULL");
    goto err2;
  }`

should be `goto err3:` I think.

Comment: no worries. on the state of memory when arr[1] malloc fails, only arr and arr[0] are valid references. you could call free(arr[1]) since arr[1] is null but err2 fits better with convention and only incrementing your error level after successful operations

Comment: A 2D pointer `realloc` can be done with nothing more than `void`. You are reallocating pointers. A pointer, is a pointer, is a pointer... They are all `sizeof (a pointer)`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin if youre saying that i could have declared temp as a void * then yes i could have - it doesnt matter its just a pointer location for realloc to return. otherwise i dont understand - please clarify

Comment: You got it, it doesn't matter, so you can create/use a generic `realloc_2d` routine for all pointer-to-pointer-to-type reallocations. The only other note would be *Why realloc every time?*. It is far more efficient to allocate a reasonably anticipated number of pointers to begin with, then realloc only when the limit is reached rather than calling realloc *over-and-over-and-over* for each single allocation.

Comment: yes, ive answered the use case where the user doesnt know how to reallocate ( command_count could just as easily have been 32 as two )

Comment: Yes, I figured, no complaints there, but it is always good to pass on a few optimization hints as you go.

Answer (score 0):

The figurative head of the nail is that you've declared `arr` to be an array of 1 `char *` (which is `arr[0]`), but you're accessing out of bounds (`arr[1]`).

As I previously mentioned in the comments, the sheer magnitude that is the number of mistakes indicates that the resource you're using isn't working. You should consider reading and doing the exercises from K&R 2E. It's tried and tested, proven by teaching thousands and thousands of students successfully for decades.

With the rest of this answer, it seems like it might be helpful to describe something tangential that K&R doesn't describe: Making use of VLAs and precedence in declarations, to show you why you're going the wrong way about this. This should demonstrate *why* you should spend more time sharpening your axe, so to say; your code should only be **one line**, after you've sharpened your axe. That one line is:

```
char (*ptr_to_array)[y] = malloc(x * sizeof *ptr_to_array);
```

---

Technically, there are three levels of indirection in the type you've described: Two dimensions of array (x and y axis, if you like) and one dimension being a pointer to that type (z axis). You can declare such a type easily by using `typedef`:

```
typedef char two_dimensional_array[42][11];
two_dimensional_array *ptr; // ptr is a pointer to two_dimensional_array.
```

This doesn't work so well for VLAs, so you need to know the alternative. Let's start with something simple:

```
char *array[42];
```

It ought to be obvious that this is an array of pointers, because I've told you that it is. How would you have read it as an array? Read the identifier as X, then read the part to the right of the identifier as Y, then read the part to the left of the identifier as Z, and form this sentence:

> ```
>   X   is       Y     of   Z
> array is an array 42 of char *
> ```

---

Now consider something a little more complex:

```
char *array_of_array[42][11];
```

I'll leave this as an exercise to those wishing to test their understanding. Comment below and I'll tell you whether you got it right or not. Please remove your comment if you get it right, so you don't spoil for the next person...

---

In the following example, you should read the brackets first, because brackets denote precedence. It's the same pattern, but applied recursively, reading the stuff inside the brackets first.

```
char (*ptr)[42][11];
```

Your eyes should be drawn to `ptr` first, as usual (to establish X), and there's nothing to the right hand side of it inside the brackets, so your eyes should then be drawn to the `*` inside the brackets, denoting that it's a pointer.

Then your eyes should be drawn to the right-hand side, outside of the brackets, following the pattern we established earlier. There are two dimensions of array there, and they read from left to right. So the pointer (one dimension) points to an array that has two dimensions.

Finally, your eyes should be drawn to the far left-hand side of the declaration to read the remainder of the type, outside of the brackets.

I encourage you to describe in comments what you think the type of `ptr` is.

---

Assuming you understood all of that correctly, the following should be easy for you to decipher, and seems to fulfill your requirements:

```
char (*ptr_to_array)[y] = malloc(x * sizeof *ptr_to_array);
```